# Openid /Oauth implementation For Windows application

Tags: dotnetopenauth, google-openid, google-oauth

How to implement openid /oauth in windows application.What are the necessary things to be considered?

Comment: That seems an overly broad question. Can you please be more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issuing OpenIDs doesn't apply at all to a client application. It only applies to web apps.

Client apps can certainly be OAuth consumers/clients. You can see the [DotNetOpenAuth OAuthConsumerWpf](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/archive/master.zip) sample for an example of this.

Comment: I want to implement Google oauth in my windows application.how can i do this.It would be really helpful if you can provide me with some samples.

Comment: I am creating a windows form application in which login functionality needs to be implemented.I want users to gain access to application only after they are authenticated using their gmail account.Can i do this using DotNetOpenAuth  if yes then how?Kindly provide with some useful samples it would really be appreciated..

Comment: Successfully implemented OAuth using DotNetOpenAuth :)

Comment: Great. Just FYI, preventing access to a WinForms application (or any local app) based on network authentication isn't entirely secure (since the network can be spoofed by another process on the computer). The only reliable thing you can achieve is *authorization* to resources that are themselves available only over the network. For example, if Google is storing your data, then requiring the user to authenticate using their Gmail account can work, since if they somehow circumvented it, they'd also thwart their own access to the Google remote data.